# JobFanIn Plugin is not working as expected

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, pipeline, build-pipeline-plugin

I configured [Job FanIn Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JobFanIn+Plugin) to create a pipeline when certain jobs where completed (**diagram 1**):

```
                              -----
                         ----|  C  |----
-------     -------     |     -----     |      ----
|  A  | --> |  B  | --> |               |---> | E  |
-------     -------     |     -----     |      ----
                         ----|  D  |----
                              -----
```

I did the configuration on Job **E** but it is not working at all and it is generating a double trigger of my job **E** (**diagram 2**):

```
                              -----      ----
                         ----|  C  |--->|  E |
-------     -------     |     -----      ----
|  A  | --> |  B  | --> |               
-------     -------     |     -----      ----
                         ----|  D  |--->|  E |
                              -----      ----
```

I was expecting the **Diagram 1**.

### Jenkins Configuration

[image]

### Jenkins Pipeline View

[image]

Comment: Also experiencing this issue! Did you find a way to resolve it? Any help would be appreciated.